# MenuItemImage get touch coordinates

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I have a MenuItemImage when touched calls the registered callback.

void callback(Ref* pSender)
{
   ...
}

Is it possible from pSender to get the actual touch coordinates??
This way I can see if the touched pixel is transparent on the image or not.

Comment: you would have to modify the ccmenu class

Comment: Is it possible if I create my own MenuItemImage Class derived from MenuItemImage ?  From here use the onTouchBegan...

Comment: if i remember correctly all touches are handled in ccmenu not the items